# How to convert number to character using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert `1234567890 = ABCDEFGHIJ`, For eg. `360 to CFJ`

I know how to do it for single character:

```
var chr = String.fromCharCode(97 + n); // where n is 0, 1, 2 ...
```

but not sure how can I do it for multiple/group of number at once: For eg. `230 to BCJ`

Comment: What? Why should `1234567890` end up as `ABCDEFGHIJ`? What are your conversion criteria?

Comment: Without any criteria is hard to say, you could just output a random string. Or you could interpret the integer as a Base64 value and output the corresponding string, or... lots of options. Unless your criteria is `A = 1, B = 2, C = 3...`? Then you could store the conversions in an array and convert the characters one by one using it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This would work:

```js
function convert(num) {
    return num
        .toString()    // convert number to string
        .split('')     // convert string to array of characters
        .map(Number)   // parse characters as numbers
        .map(n => (n || 10) + 64)   // convert to char code, correcting for J
        .map(c => String.fromCharCode(c))   // convert char codes to strings
        .join('');     // join values together
}

console.log(convert(360));
console.log(convert(230));
```

And just for fun, here's a version using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#or):

```js
const digitStrToChar = R.pipe(
    Number,                      // convert digit to number
    R.or(R.__, 10),              // correct for J
    R.add(64),                   // add 64
    R.unary(String.fromCharCode) // convert char code to letter
);

const convert = R.pipe(
   R.toString,            // convert number to string
   R.split(''),           // split digits into array
   R.map(digitStrToChar), // convert digit strings to letters
   R.join('')             // combine letters
);

console.log(convert(360));
console.log(convert(230));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

The `fromCharCode` accepts a list of arguments as parameter.

`String.fromCharCode(72, 69, 76, 76, 79);` for example will print 'HELLO'.

Your example data is invalid though. The letter 'A' for example is 65. You'll need to create a comma separated argument that you feed into the function. If you don't provide it as a comma separated arg, you'll be trying to parse a single key code which will most likely fail.

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log( (1234567890 + '').replace(/\d/g, c => 'JABCDEFGHI'[c] ) )

console.log( String.fromCharCode(...[...1234567890 + ''].map(c => (+c || 10) | 64)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define your alphabet up front. For your snippet, you seem to want 1-9 to map to A-I, and 0 to J, so:

```
const alphabet = "JABCDEFGHI";
```

Then it's just a matter of using each digit of the number as an index in that alphabet:

```
function numberToString(num) {
    // Split out each digit of the number:
    const digits = Math.floor(num).toString().split("").map(Number);

    // Then create a new string using the alphabet:
    return digits.reduce((str, digit) => {
        return str + alphabet[digit];
    }, "");
}
```

That should satisfy your constraints. Here's an example of this in action:

```js
const alphabet = "JABCDEFGHI";

function numberToString(num) {
    // Split out each digit of the number:
    const digits = Math.floor(num).toString().split("").map(Number);

    // Then create a new string using the alphabet:
    return digits.reduce((str, digit) => {
        return str + alphabet[digit];
    }, "");
}

console.log(numberToString(360)) // CFJ
console.log(numberToString(230)) // BCJ
```

Answer (score 1):

For uppercase, `97` was the wrong offset, and it didn't give you the desired result with `0` being `J`.

> *360 to CFJ*
>
> *230 to BCJ*

```js
function convert(n) {
  return String.fromCharCode(
   ...n.toString().split("").map(c => (+c||10) + 0x40)
  );
}

console.log(convert(360));
console.log(convert(230));

function onInput(elm){
  console.clear()
  console.log( convert(elm.value) )
}
```

```html
<input oninput="onInput(this)">
```

---

And  you can do this without the initial string conversion.

```js
function convert(n) {
  var a = Array(Math.floor(Math.log10(n))+1);
  var i = a.length;
  while (n) {
    a[--i] = ((n%10)||10) + 0x40;
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(...a);
}

console.log(convert(360));
console.log(convert(230));
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: map it

```js
const from = 1234567890;

const answer = from
  .toString() // convert to string, ignore this if it's already a string
  .split('') // split to array
  .map(x => +x + 97) // convert to char code number
  .map(String.fromCharCode) // convert to char code
  .join(''); // convert back to string

console.log(answer)
```

Option 2: pass in multiple params

```js
const from = 1234567890;

const fromCharCodes = from
  .toString() // convert to string, ignore this if it's already a string
  .split('') // split to array
  .map(x => +x + 97) // convert to char code number

const answer = String.fromCharCode(...fromCharCodes);

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: These both produce the wrong result. The first one is especially bad because the result is filled with spaces.

Comment: the first result doesn't produce spaces. Both result return `bcdefghija`. The charcode logic is following the logic mentioned in the question `String.fromCharCode(97 + n)` as the author mention that's the logic for single result, what he doesn't sure is how to implement that when for multiple string. So, I don't think it's wrong @JLRishe

Comment: It's the question itself not consistent - the logic provided in the question and the explanation of expected result is not consistent.

My answer is assuming the logic provided is expected, and my answer is solving the multiple char conversion part.

Comment: _"the first result doesn't produce spaces."_ Dude, click the **Run code snippet** button under your own code. It produces a string of length 30 for an input of 10 digits, filled with non-displayable characters. _"My answer is assuming the logic provided is expected, and my answer is solving the multiple char conversion part."_ It doesn't provide the requested outputs for the specified inputs. You can't just make up your own requirements because you don't understand the original requirements.